# Run Comand on all files (folders ad subfolders)

Tags: shell, shell-script

All, I have a lot of PDF files. Does there exist a way to apply to all PDFs in folder and sub-folders at one time?

Example, I have:

- /pdf/test/pdfa.pdf
- /pdf/example/aa/test.pdf

I'd like to apply this command on each file:

```
$ convert -density 200x200 -quality 60 \
    -compress jpeg filename.pdf filename_compress.pdf
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @jasonwryan That question is very similar but the OP's desired naming scheme here requires some additional tricks.

Comment: @John1024 I disagree (obviously); the principle is simple enough, any adjustments are incidental to the overall approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simplest if we go for a slightly different naming scheme for the output files.  This converts `filename.pdf` to `filename.pdf-compress.pdf`:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec convert -density 200x200 -quality 60 -compress jpeg {} {}-compress.pdf ';'
```

If you want to keep your original naming scheme, use:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec env f={} bash -c 'convert -density 200x200 -quality 60 -compress jpeg "$f" ${f%.pdf}_compress.pdf' ';'
```